# Secure SSH Server from brute-force?

Tags: ssh, security, vps

I'm just a newbie in Linux and recently got a VPS (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Server).
How can I secure its ssh server from brute-force attacks?

Comment: There's a lot of info on the internet.  Until you get something implemented, make sure all passwords are very secure.  But it's better to use private key encryption, which is actually very easy to implement, but requires your key on the remote system.

Comment: @MartyFried Private keys are used for authentication, not encryption.

Comment: Oh, right... I knew that.